# Using par(new=T) in loops: different colors?

Tags: r, loops, plot, multiple-columns

I wanted to use `par(new = TRUE)` to plot my plots which were generated in a loop over another.
But how do I make sure, that every new plot has a another color?
It is all black and overlayed now, so that I cannot distinguish the plots anymore:

```r
for(i in names(extensor_raw[2:9])){
  # Coerce a data.frame into an 'emg' object
  x <- as.emg(extensor_raw[i], samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")  ##do this for every channel
  
  # Compute the rectified signal
  x_rect <- rectification(x)
  
  # Filter the rectified signal
  y <- lowpass(x_rect, cutoff = 100)
  
  # plot the original channel, the filtered channel and the LE-envelope
  plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope"))
  par(new = TRUE) 
}
```

[image]

I tried to implement the following: I tried to include `col = rainbow(9)[i]`, but this only gives me a blank plot:

```r
plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope") , col=rainbow(9)[i])
par(new = TRUE)
```

[image]

As asked for in the comments I have used `dput(y)` (not sure whether the postion was right:

```r
for(i in names(extensor_raw[2:9])){
  # Coerce a data.frame into an 'emg' object
  x <- as.emg(extensor_raw[i], samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")  ##do this for every channel
  
  # Compute the rectified signal
  x_rect <- rectification(x)
  
  # Filter the rectified signal
  y <- lowpass(x_rect, cutoff = 50)

  # plot the original channel, the filtered channel and the 
  # LE-envelope
  plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope extensor") , col=rainbow(9)[i])
  par(new=T) 
}
    
dput(y)
```

That is the result:

[image]

- there is still the empty plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the `for`-loop to iterate over `names(extensor_raw)`. That means that `i` will be a character in every loop. However, to define any color, you need a numeric value. The solution is to iterate over an integer sequence instead:

```r
seq_along(names(extensor_raw[2:9]))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

That way, `col = rainbow(9)[i]` will work, e.g.:

```r
i <- 5
rainbow(9)[i]
# [1] "#00FFAA"
```

---

I also modified the code to work with a single `plot` call. From there, we just add lines with the `lines` function. I do this with an `if-else` statement.

Furthermore, we'd need to define the `y` range properly. So, we can do:

```r
y_range <- c(0, max(extensor_raw[2:9]))
```

We can then use `y_range` in `plot`.

The full code:

```r
for(i in seq_along(names(extensor_raw[2:9]))) {
  x <- as.emg(extensor_raw[i], samplingrate = 1000, units = "mV")  ##do this for every channel
  x_rect <- rectification(x)
  y <- lowpass(x_rect, cutoff = 100)

  if (i == 1) {
    plot(y, main = "LE-envelope", col = rainbow(9)[i], ylim = y_range)
  } else {
    lines(y, col = rainbow(9)[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope", i), col=rainbow(9)[i])
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your fast answer. Sadly, this did not work because I get a blank image then with no plots at all instead of black or even rainbow ones. I think it might have to do with how the loop is iterated. But I could not figure the problem out.

Comment: You put the parentheses in the wrong place.  You wrote `plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope",  col=rainbow(9)[i]))`   but it should be `plot(y, main = paste("LE-envelope"),  col=rainbow(9)[i])`

Comment: Yes, thank you, I see that with my code and that mistake I get only black plots (because it's referring to the title) I have corrected it to your version but then I get a blank plot. I have updated it in my question above

Comment: After you run your code,  `y` should have the last value it had during the loop, the one for  `names(extensor_raw[9]`.  Please run `dput(y)` and paste the result in your question so that we can test this out.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I am not quiet sure where the dput(y) should be placed?

Comment: After you run your loop,  just run that code.  If you want,  you could put it just after the `}` that ends the  loop.